# simple sql query, combine results and divide

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to get **2 counts** from **2 tables** and work out the percentage like for a MySQL db:

1. `select field_one,  count(*) as COUNT_ONE from table1 group by field_one;`
2. `select other_field,count(*) as COUNT_TWO from table2 group by other_field;`

I want to combine the results and have `FINAL_COUNT=(COUNT_ONE/COUNT_TWO) * 100` for percentage ?

Comment: How are the tables joined? By field_one = other_field?

Comment: Does field_one and other_field have same values in two tables?

Comment: You are using group by so will have multiple results for each table presumably?

Comment: yes same value, actually also same name but wanted to make sure they are seen as distinct in quetion.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

quick and dirty:

```
select (a.count_one / b.count_two) * 100 as final_count from 
(select field_one, count(*) as count_one from table1 group by field_one) a,
(select field_two, count(*) as count_two from table2 group by field_two) b
where a.field_one = b.field_two
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select sum(((QUERY FROM TABLE 1) / (QUERY FROM TABLE 2)) * 100) as percentage
```

Comment: This is delicious! But FYI: you do NOT need `sum()` in code, this suffices: `select ( ((QUERY FROM TABLE 1) / (QUERY FROM TABLE 2)) * 100 ) as percentage`

Comment: Marco you're right. This solution is even better cause faster to write :).

Comment: If your playing with counts when you do this you probably want something like `select (( select 100.0*count(*) query 1) / (query 2)) as percentage` as your decimal will truncate before it hits the 100.0