# SQL Count divided by count

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm having a small issue, I just want to see a count over a count but i read some replies and I'm not sure they work. Im using google bigquery to run the query, I just want to see a query over the total rows in the db. Something like this:

```
select count(gender) from db
where order_number like "2%" and gender <> ""
```

this is to be divided by

```
select count(*) from db
```

I thought maybe I could do this:

```
select count(gender)/(select count(*) from db)
from db
where order number ...
```

But that didn't work. Any help would really be appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: Yes. What we really like is comments like 'that didn't work'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [simple sql query, combine results and divide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521944/simple-sql-query-combine-results-and-divide)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
select sum(case when order_number like "2%" and gender <> "" then 1.0 else 0 end) / count(*)
from db;
```

I don't think Bigquery allows subqueries in the `select` statement.